# Modify template file on the fly and post it to server using curl?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I have below input `temp.txt` file which I need to post it using curl -

```
{
  "query":"\n{\n  data(clientId: 1234, filters: [{key: \"o\", value: 100}], key: \"world\") {\n    title\n    type\n    pottery {\n      text\n      pid\n      href\n      count\n      resource\n    }\n  }\n}"
}
```

Below is how I am sourcing the file and posting it to server. Everything works fine without any issues.

```
curl 'url' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' \
  -H 'Origin: url' \
  --data-binary "@/Users/david/Downloads/temp.txt" \
  --compressed \
  --silent \
  --output /dev/null \
  --write-out '%{http_code}'
```

Now I am trying to post above curl request for multiple `clientId's` as shown in my above `temp.txt` file. I have like 10 different `clientId's` for which I want to post the same json but for each different `clientId`.

Is there any way I can make this generic enough so that it can read `clientId's` from some other file say - `clientIds.txt` which will have list of all `clientId's` and then it can post each json for its own `clientId` to the server?

I can have content in `clientIds.txt` file as -

```
1234
9812
6751
2181
```

Now I should make json like this for each `clientId` and post it to server. Is this possible to do by any chance? I can have `temp.txt` file as the template where `clientId` field can be filled from `clientIds.txt` file and then we can post it out to the server but I am not sure how we can do this in shell script?

**For clientId: 9812**

```
{
   "query":"\n{\n  data(clientId: 9812, filters: [{key: \"o\", value: 100}], key: \"world\") {\n    title\n    type\n    pottery {\n      text\n      pid\n      href\n      count\n      resource\n    }\n  }\n}"
}
```

**For clientId: 6751**

```
{
   "query":"\n{\n  data(clientId: 6751, filters: [{key: \"o\", value: 100}], key: \"world\") {\n    title\n    type\n    pottery {\n      text\n      pid\n      href\n      count\n      resource\n    }\n  }\n}"
}
```

**For clientId: 2181**

```
{
   "query":"\n{\n  data(clientId: 2181, filters: [{key: \"o\", value: 100}], key: \"world\") {\n    title\n    type\n    pottery {\n      text\n      pid\n      href\n      count\n      resource\n    }\n  }\n}"
}
```

**Update**

I tried something like this in my bash script but I cannot make it work as I am confuse on few things. How can I replace my template json file for each clientId and then post that json to the server using curl -

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # this below line isn't working
    cat temp.txt | sed 's/clientId:[^ ]*/clientId:$line/'
    # and how should I use new json to post curl
done < clientIds.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bash file that loops through that list:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for word in $(< clientIds.txt)
do
    echo "curl $word"
done
```

replace the `echo curl` command with your working curl command, but the ***$word*** variable is the next ***clientId*** in order

> Or just ran that code-block directly in the cli.

Comment: yeah that part I got it. My only confusion is how to change `temp.txt` template for each `clientId` from `clientIds.txt` file.

Comment: Also updated my question with what I have tried. I am running it on my mac for now.

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. My answer described how to change the template for each word from the file in question.